# How do I discover which class has declared a field?

Tags: java, reflection

If I have an hierarchical class:

```
class Root {
    private String requestedField; // This is private, so Class<Root> is not the owner!
}

class RealOwner extends Root {
    public String requestedField; // This is visible from Class<Distant>

    RealOwner() { super(); }
}

class Middle extends RealOwner {
    Middle() { super(); }
}

class Distant extends Middle {
    Distant() { super(); }
}
```

Now I if I have a `Class<Distant>`, what is the proper way to get the class object which has declared the `requestField` that is visible from the `Distant` class?

```
class Retriever {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        Field field = Distant.class.getField("requestedField");
        Class<?> declaredBy = // Where did this field came from?
    }
}
```

Comment: private fields and methods will not be inherited

Comment: You would get the field from `Root` or `RealOwner` (since they're different strings), and then then invoke the `Field#get` on the appropriate instance of your `Distant` object

Comment: @rollback: Yeah, but look down a bit. There's a second, non-private field with the same name.

Comment: @rollback exactly, that's why I added it to the example, the `Root`'s requestedField is not visible from `Distant` but the `RealOwner`'s requestedField is as long as both classes have the same package

Comment: I think `getField` only works with actually public fields - a package-private field won't be visible through `getField` either.

Comment: That's true @user2357112  I'm fixing

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem not really, that would throw `NoSuchFieldException` from `Distant.class.getField("requestedField")`, I need to discover the `Class<RealOwner>`, I'm looking for a way to get that result properly.

Comment: Did you try it?  I don't believe it would throw that.

Comment: `getDeclaringClass` works in this case. http://ideone.com/ruGTuD The alternative is to e.g. loop through each `getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields()` and find the first field with the given name which is public.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I overlooked your comment, somehow I thought that you were talking about the `getDeclaredField` in `Class`. That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @EJP `RealOwner`'s requestField is public, the `Root`'s field was added as a example of field which should not be returned, I'm going to add a comment about it to the example

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem you should add your comment as answer, it solved the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `getDeclaringClass()`  method of the `Field` class to find which class a field is defined in.